# How to display map like foursquare using bootstrap 3.0

Tags: css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

i am not sure about the css and html structure

here is my html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">  
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">View Plan</div>
        <div class="dam-holder"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="gmaps"><div id="gmap_geocoding"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.gmaps {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gmaps > div{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   /* position: absolute; */
   z-index: 0;   
}
```

you can see the map in action here https://foursquare.com/explore?mode=url&near=Tokyo%2C%20T%C5%8Dky%C5%8D-to%2C%20Japan&q=Coffee%20Shop

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS `position:absolute` to place the map accordingly. Set all of the containers to 100% height, and use `overflow-y:scroll` to make the left col independently scroll. CSS3 `height:calc(100% - 0);` can be used to make sure the map is always full height.

```
#map-canvas {
    width:33.3333%;
    height:calc(100% - 0);
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Here's a working example that should help you...

http://www.bootply.com/129229

Comment: i prefer using the window scroll and i still believe only using bootstrap css without any customs

Comment: No.. it won't look like the Foursquare page unless use customize/override the Bootstrap CSS

Comment: ok well. i dont mind to customize the css but still lokking ways to have window scroll instead of div

Comment: hi is there any workaround using window scroll instead of div scroll

Comment: It may require some tweaks. Have you made an effort to play with it yourself? I made a few changes, and came up with this: http://bootply.com/129821 -- Go ahead and accept my answer since it answers your original question

Comment: your solution work but unfortunately i really miss the window scroll instead of div scroll. i have to playaround a bit with `top` and `right` and appropriate `width` adjustment. Thank you very much

Comment: when apply on chrome, there is a strange grey line within the map. it's obvious. Have you ever experience this?